# Websphere Liberty profile - transacted Websphere MQ connection factory

Tags: websphere, apache-camel, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

Trying to get my Liberty profile server to create a transacted jmsConnectionFactory to my instance of Websphere message queue.

`Liberty profile v 8.5.5.5
 Websphere MQ 7.x`

I've tried to change the jmsQueueConnectionFactory to jmsXAQueueConnectionFactory but it does not help -> Then it seems to just ignore it and doesn't connect to the MQ

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>wmqJmsClient-1.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="D:\wlp\wmq\wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

  <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/wmqCF" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr6">
    <properties.wmqJms
            transportType="CLIENT"
            hostName="hostname"
            port="1514"
            channel="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"
            queueManager="QM"           
            />
  </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

  <connectionManager id="ConMgr6" maxPoolSize="2"/>

  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
  <application id="App"
               location="...\app.war"
               name="App" type="war"/>
  <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                httpPort="9080"
                httpsPort="9443"/>
</server>
```

**log**

```
2015-04-23 17:07:14,981 [JmsConsumer[A0]] WARN  ultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'A0' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not commit JMS transaction; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0014: It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a nontransacted session. The application called a method that must not be called on a nontransacted session. Change the application program to remove this behavior.
2015-04-23 17:07:14,983 [JmsConsumer[A0]] INFO  ultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

**Camel code**

```
public static JmsComponent mqXAComponentTransacted(InitialContext context, String jndiName) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    return JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted((XAQueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(jndiName));
}
```

Comment: Is Camel needing a full XA connection factory here? Is it going to be the xa coordinator or will it just use a jms transacted session?

Comment: Before I did not use the JNDI lookup and used
JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactoryAdapter)
The connectionFactoryAdapter was to set credentials, and it used MQXAQueueConnectionFactory. 
This did work, it commited to the producer when it was ready with processing the message, but it does not now.
What I need is that Camel makes a commit once it has processed the message, so it is not lost in case the QueueManager goes down or the application goes down while processing a message. Using JmsComponent.jmsComponent() would just consume the message from the queue and it could be lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with:

```
public static JmsComponent mqXAComponentTransacted(InitialContext context, String connectionFactoryJndiName, String userTransactionJndiName) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    LOG.info("Setting up JmsComponent using jndi lookup");
    final JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager((UserTransaction) context.lookup(userTransactionJndiName));
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryJndiName);
    final JmsComponent jmsComponent = JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory, (PlatformTransactionManager) jtaTransactionManager);
    jmsComponent.setTransacted(false);
    jmsComponent.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
    return jmsComponent;
}
```