# Spring JMS Message Redelivery not working as expected for CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, ibm-mq, spring-jms

My environment: `spring 4.1`, `JBoss EAP 6.4`, `IBM MQ 8.0`:

Messages are not redelivered in the case where `Listener` throws `RuntimeException`.

I have the following in `JmsConfig`:

```
@Bean
DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer(QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory, JndiDestinationResolver dr, MessageListener ml) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer mlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    mlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    mlc.setMessageListener(ml);
    mlc.setDestinationName(jndiInQueue);
    mlc.setDestinationResolver(dr);
    mlc.setSessionTransacted(true);
    mlc.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return mlc;
}
```

If I use a `JmsTransactionManager` and pass it to the above method and use like so:

`mlc.setTransactionManager(tm)`

Following warnings are written to the log:

`It is not valid to commit a non-transacted session`, and the behavior is the same, no redelivery.

`ConnectionFactory` is obtained via `JNDI`, I wonder if sourcing the `ConnectionFactory` through jndi has something to do with this?

From the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` Javadocs:

> In order to consistently arrange for redelivery with any container variant, consider "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode or - preferably - setting "sessionTransacted" to "true" instead

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413784/jms-message-redelivery-on-exception-in-jms-listener) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Flip your ack mode to Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED instead of CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE.

Client Ack mode doesn't work as most folks want it.. and is a common "gotcha" in JMS. It acknowledges current message AND all previous messages in the session. It is not per-message acknowledgement.

Edit:

Also check related post-- IBM MQ may require you to use the "XA" versions of the connection factory class.

ref: [Websphere Liberty profile - transacted Websphere MQ connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827894/websphere-liberty-profile-transacted-websphere-mq-connection-factory)